# AWS Glue AccessDeniedException in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I am running the "Explain Credit Decisions" solution from Sagemaker Studio. I am following the instructions in the solution notebooks. The solution has been launched with my root user id. But when running `1_datasets.ipynb` I am getting the below error when running the step
`glue_run_id = glue.start_workflow(config.GLUE_WORKFLOW)`

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetJob operation: User: arn:aws:sts::myaccountid:assumed-role/rolecreatedbystack/GlueJobRunnerSession is not authorized to perform: glue:GetJob on resource: arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:myaccountid:job/sagemaker-soln-ecd-js-foccb4-job
```

The Cloud Formation stacks are created and the scripts should create the required roles and access which are needed to run this solution.
I have to run a POC with this solution with my custom data. So can you please help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker is attempting to start a [Glue Workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/start-workflow-run.html) but getting access denied. This is not a problem with SageMaker, it appears your CloudFormation stack is not assigning correct permissions.

Adding the permissions policy `glue:GetJob` to the role like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-managingrole-editing-console.html#roles-modify_permissions-policy) should fix this. If your role already has an appropriate Glue policy assigned, make sure your AWS environment does not have [session policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_roles.html#troubleshoot_roles_session-policy) preventing this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I had to correct the permission manually. But I tried on another account where the AWS CloudFormation stack assigned the permission automatically without any manual intervention. I am yet to troubleshoot the issue.